# Complex Vector spaces inner product superposition axiom

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, quantum-mechanics

In my studies of Quantum mechanics, the following problem with complex vector spaces has come up, specifically as regards the inner product in such a space. Now in Shankars "Principles of Quantum Mechanics 2nd ed" on page 8, 9, the linearity/antilinearity property is explained in a way such that the First vector in an inner product would have to be conjugated:
$ <V|aW+bZ> = a<V|W>+b<V|Z>  whereas   <aW+bZ|V> = a^*<W|V>+b^*<Z|V>$, where a and b are complex scalars, $^*$ means conjugate and V,W,Z are vector elements. 
In Herstein's "Topics in Algebra" however, the opposite  is assumed (see page 192/193): here, $(aW+bZ) \cdot V = aW\cdot V+bZ\cdot V$ while $V\cdot (aW+bZ) = a^*V\cdot W+b^*V\cdot Z $.

In other  words, according to Shankar, superposition in the first vector will let the scalars come out as conjugates, while according to Herstein, superposition in the second vector will let the scalars come out as conjugates.

Can someone explain this contradiction? Does it have something to do with the braket convention? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if you define
$$
\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf w = \langle \mathbf w, \mathbf v \rangle
$$
you find that both equations are consistent. The main point is that you want
$$
\langle c\mathbf w, c\mathbf v \rangle = |c|^2 \langle \mathbf w, \mathbf v \rangle
$$
and you get that in both definitions.

Comment: I think you're right. But is this (vw = <w,v>) the accepted definition? It sure would make sense, but is it conventional? And if so, any reason for that convention?

Comment: I have no idea what's conventional. The Herstein definition is the one I've seen most often (both for "dot" and "angle bracket" versions of inner product), and it sort of matches up with the usual notion that $|z|^2 = z \bar{z}$, in which we put the bar on the *second* factor. But the physicists may have some good reason for conjugating the first factor, or may have simply invented things concurrently and made the opposite choice somewhere. Or maybe it's just done in Shankar's book -- you might want to look at a few other quantum books and see.

Comment: For those who are interested: Section 1.3 in Shankar provides a good explanation of the braket convention. Also, Herstein's Chapter on dual spaces contains further exposition on that concept.